# After Effects expression: one layer's expression function breaks when referencing another layer

Tags: after-effects

I have two layers in my After Effects comp:

**Layer 1:** expression contains a `function` that retrieves layer 2's `position`

**Layer 2:** contains an expression that calculates `position` relative to layer 1

If I comment out the line of code in **Layer 1** that references **Layer 2**, the `function` works.  If I allow that line to run, the `function` doesn't work - and no error message is displayed.

There must be a rendering/compiling order to expression code that I'm missing.  If anyone can offer some insight, I appreciate it.